# Confusion with `include` inside a class definition

Tags: ruby

In the code below, I don't understand why the classes are returning their names.

```
module Show
  def show_string
    p "hi"
  end
end

class Foo
  @x=12
  include Show
end
# => Foo

class Test
  include Show
end
# => Test
```

To see the reason, I inserted `object_id`. And it is now showing the object id.

```
class Foo
  @x=12
  (include Show).object_id
end
# => 10681980

class Too
  @x=12
  (include Show).object_id.inspect
end
# => "10648020"
```

I didn't create any object on `Foo.new` and `Too.new`. Are such objects created there inside the class definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a module/class, the return value is the last expression within the body:

```
module A; :foo end
# => :foo
```

When the body is empty, it returns `nil`.

```
module A; end
# => nil
```

Now, notice that the return value of `include` is the module that is including. You can see this in the `main` environment:

```
p (include A)
# => Object
```

So when you do `include A` within the module body of `B`, the return value should be the value of  the last expression `include A`, which is `B`.

```
module B
  include A
end
# => B
```

You have not created any instance of `Foo` or `Too`. The object ids that you are seeing are the object ids of the class `Foo` and `Too`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. But does it mean whenever we are creating new class definitions, `object_id` s are also created of them or it is the case with only the `include` statement?

Comment: Any object has an object id from the beginning. A class is an object.

Comment: Yeah! I got the point now.. I am happy... YOU are my SIR :) here is my try - `class Foo
 end
#=> nil
 Foo.object_id
#=> 9189204`

Comment: Do you have this [book pdf version](http://www.informit.com/store/ruby-way-solutions-and-techniques-in-ruby-programming-9780132480390) version with you? If you have - would you give me to read?

Answer (score 1):

In your first code example, the classes aren't returning their names.  They are returning *the classes themselves*, which irb renders as the class name.

For your second block of code, the return value of #include is the class doing the including.  The object ID's you're seeing in the second block of code are those of Foo and Too.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. I am asking why without `.new` objects are being created?